# How can I verify that RemoveRange has been called on a mock DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am using Moq to test code that calls `RemoveRange` on a `DbSet<T>`.  I have mocked the context object and `DbSet`, but when I attempt to Verify that RemoveRange was called, I get "Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times."  The method I'm testing has this code:

```
IEnumerable<Thing> thingsToRemove = GetThingsToRemove();
DataContext.Things.RemoveRange(thingsToRemove);
```

My test code looks something like this:

```
var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
var mockThingSet = new Mock<DbSet<Thing>>();
var testData = new List<Thing>{new Thing{Id = 1, Name = "Test Thing"}};
mockThingSet.As<IQueryable<Thing>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(testData .Provider);
mockThingSet.As<IQueryable<Thing>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(testData.Expression);
mockThingSet.As<IQueryable<Thing>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(testData.ElementType);
mockThingSet.As<IQueryable<Thing>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(testData.GetEnumerator);
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Things).Returns(mockThingSet.Object);  
//call the method being tested, then....  
mockContext.Verify(c => c.Things.RemoveRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Thing>>()), Times.Once);
```

I have stepped through the code and verified that 1) the line calling `RemoveRange` is hit and does not throw an exception and that 2) the object being passed to `RemoveRange` is an `IEnumerable<Thing>`.  I've also attempted to call `Verify` on the mocked `DbSet`, but that doesn't work either, which makes sense since the call is being made directly against the data context.

Why isn't this verifying?  How can I verify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `Verify` on the correct mock:

```
mockThingSet.Verify(c => c.RemoveRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Thing>>()), Times.Once);
```

Comment: He did try that and didnt work.. From the question: "I've also attempted to call Verify on the mocked DbSet, but that doesn't work either"